# Can I force image links in DataTables.net cells to be rendered on one line?

Tags: html, datatables

I have this DataTables controlled table, where cells in one column contain several image link elements (`<image>` elements contained in `<a>` elements). My problem is that each link is displayed on a new line within its cell. Can I somehow force that the links are displayed on a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in a somewhat imperfect fashion. I specified the column width as large enough to hold the two images to DataTables, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').dataTable({
      'aoColumnDefs': [{'sWidth': 44, 'aTargets': [-1]}]
    });
});
```